# Logic to check if exact ids are present in a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some sample data like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([ID], [FK_ID], [TYPE_ID])
VALUES
    (1, 10, 1),
    (2, 11, 1), (3, 11, 2),    
    (4, 12, 1), (5, 12, 2), (6, 12, 3),
    (7, 14, 2), (8, 14, 3)
```

Now, here I am trying to check if in each group by `FK_ID` we have exact match of `TYPE_ID` values `1 & 2`.

So, the expected output is like:

1. `(1, 10, 1)` this should fail

   - As in group `FK_ID = 10` we only have one record
2. `(2, 11, 1), (3, 11, 2)` this should pass

   - As in group `FK_ID = 11` we have two records.
   - And both the `TYPE_ID` are matching `1 & 2` values.
3. `(4, 12, 1), (5, 12, 2), (6, 12, 3)` this should also fail

   - As we have 3 records here.
4. `(7, 14, 2), (8, 14, 3)` this should also fail

   - Even though we have exact two records, it should fail as the `TYPE_ID` here are not matching with `1 & 2` values.

Here is my attempt:

```
select * 
from mytable t1
where exists (select count(t2.TYPE_ID) 
              from mytable t2 
              where t2.FK_ID = t1.FK_ID
                and t2.TYPE_ID in (1, 2)
              group by t2.FK_ID 
              having count(t2.TYPE_ID) = 2);
```

This is not working as expected, because it also pass for `FK_ID = 12` which has three records.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/edc0e/2/0)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several different ways of doing this. One could be:

```
SELECT FK_ID 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY FK_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
AND MIN(TYPE_ID) = 1
AND MAX(TYPE_ID) = 2
```

Comment: @CodeNewbie The best way to thank someone in Stackoverflow is to accept it as your answer

Comment: How can we do that? I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can add min and max to the group by query

```
select t1.* from mytable t1,
 ( select fk_id, count(*) As cnt from mytable  

              Group by fk_id
              Having count(*) = 2
                AND max(type_id)=2
                ANd min(Type_id) = 1) As t2
 Where t1.fk_id = t2.fk_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, but less optimal than Nenad's, is to use SELECT INTO (with output to temporary table) and then with another query SELECT only these rows that have proper TYPE_ID values.